# PDFBox Inconsistent PDTextField Autosize Behavior after setValue

Tags: java, jruby, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox for configuration of `PDTextField`'s on a PDF document where I load `Lato` onto the document using:

```
font = PDType0Font.load(
    @j_pd_document,
    java.io.FileInputStream.new('/path/to/Lato-Regular.ttf')
) # => Lato-Regular

font_name = pd_default_resources.add(font).get_name # => F4
```

I then pass the font_name into a `default_appearance_string` for the `PDTextField` like so:

```
j_text_field.set_default_appearance("/#{font_name} 0 Tf 0 g") # where font_name is
                                                              # passed in from above
```

The issue now occurs when I proceed to invoke `setValue` on the `PDTextField`. Because I set the `font_size` in the `defaultAppearanceString` to `0`, according to the library's [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleForm.java), the text should scale itself to fit in the text box's given area. However, the behaviour of this 'scale-to-fit' is inconsistent for certain fields: it does not always choose the largest font size to fit in the `PDTextField`. Might there be any further configuration that might allow for this to happen? Below are the PDFs where I've noticed this problem occurring.

Unfilled, with fonts loaded:
http://www.filedropper.com/0postfontload

Filled, with inconsisteny textbox text sizing:
http://www.filedropper.com/file_327

**Side Note**: I am using PDFBox through `jruby` which is just a integration layer that allows Ruby to invoke Java libraries. All java methods for the library available; a java method like `thisExampleMethod` would have a one-to-one translation into ruby `this_example_method`.

---

**Updates**

In response to comments, the appearances that are incorrect in the second uploaded file example are:

- 1st page Resident Name field (two text fields that have text that is too small for the given input field size)
- 2nd page Phone fields (four text fields that have text that overflows the given input field size)

Comment: Unfortunately you don't clearly indicate which fields you think are wrong. I assume you mean the *CARE PROVIDERS Address* fields where the writing appears too small in size. The problem is that the pre-existing form appearances are already trashy. If there already is a pre-existing normal appearance, PDFBox attempts to re-use it which in case of your document results in this broken appearance. You should remove the former appearances before setting values. If you think other fields incorrect, too, please indicate which fields you mean.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your response, I've updated the question with the incorrect fields in question. Does `setDefaultAppearance` on the `PDTextField` not overwrite the existing appearance of the field? Do you have a recommended approach to removing former appearances?

Comment: Concerning the Update: ***ResidentName** field* - here again the issue is due to the originally existing appearance having a size not matching the aspect ratio of the field. ***Phone** fields* - you mean the fields only showing "T e"? Those fields are configured to be comb fields with a **MaxLen** value of `2`. That appropriate explains the appearance.

Comment: @mkl Is there a way to reset the existing appearance/behaviour of a PDField completely that doesn't involve creating a new Field altogether?

Comment: There is a way to remove the existing appearance streams. BUT those old appearance stream cause only a part of your problems, as mentioned above some fields are 2 character comb fields while you want them to be something different entirely. Furthermore, you have a number of fields with multiple widgets. All the widgets of those fields automatically have the same value which does not make much sense for your form (e.g. *all* of those 2 character comb widgets represent *the same field* but surely all those office, cell, pager, and fax numbers shall not coincide).

Comment: Additionally, after removing the appearances, I saw that you are subject to the known issue [PDFBOX-4568 - Field text poorly vertically aligned](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4568) for some fields. Thus, you first need to overhaul your form definition to make it make sense, and then you have to tweak it not to be subject to PDFBOX-4568.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the 2-character comb fields you're referring to are; they're still of type `PDTextField`, except that their `COSObject` has `MAX_LEN` set to 2 right? Would it be possible for me to revert that limit by setting `MAX_LEN` to be `-1` instead? I noticed that the field becomes unfillable after trying that. To your latter point, this PDF is just an example for my use-case; I'm filling in a test value to ensure that my embedded font is working correctly by font style, and sizing. Is there a known way currently to address the vertical issue?

Comment: @mkl Just for context, the issue I was referring to in the question's upload seem to only appear on Mac OS Preview. If I open the document using adobe acrobat reader, then it does not happen. Very strange

Comment: *"setting MAX_LEN to be -1 instead"* - A comb field needs an actual maximum length. To make it arbitrary, you need to reset the comb field flag and remove the maximum length completely. *"seem to only appear on Mac OS Preview"* - certain issues were also present in ms Windows Adobe Reader. I don't know if they were the same as on Preview. Screen shots would have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially the appearances of the Resident Name fields, the Phone fields, and the Care Providers Address fields appear conspicuous. Only the former two are mentioned by the OP.

Let's inspect these fields; all screen shots are made using Adobe Reader DC on MS Windows:

#### The Resident Name fields

The filled in Resident Name fields look like this

[image: screen shot]

While the height is appropriate, the glyphs are narrower than they should be. Actually this effect can already be seen in the original PDF:

[image: screen shot]

This horizontal compression is caused by the field widget rectangles having a different aspect ratio than the respectively matching normal appearance stream bounding box:

- The widget rectangles: `[ 45.72 601.44 118.924 615.24 ]` and `[ 119.282 601.127 192.486 614.927 ]`, i.e. 73.204*13.8 in both cases.
- The appearance bounding box: `[ 0 0 147.24 13.8 ]`, i.e. 147.24*13.8.

So they have the same height but the appearance bounding box is approximately twice as wide as the widget rectangle. Thus, the text drawn normally in the appearance stream gets compressed to half its width when the appearance is displayed in the widget rectangle.

When setting the value of a field PDFBox unfortunately re-uses the appearance stream as is and only updates details from the default appearance, i.e. font name, font size, and color, and the actual text value, apparently assuming the other properties of the appearance are as they are for a reason. Thus, the PDFBox output also shows this horizontal compression

To make PDFBox create a proper appearance, it is necessary to remove the old appearances before setting the new value.

#### The Phone fields

The filled in Phone fields look like this

[image: screen shot]

and again there is a similar display in the original file

[image: screen shot]

That only the first two letters are shown even though there is enough space for the whole word, is due to the configuration of these fields: They are configured as comb fields with a maximum length of 2 characters.

To have a value here set with PDFBox displayed completely and not so spaced out, you have to remove the maximum length (or at least have to make it no less than the length of your value) and unset the comb flag.

#### The Care Providers Address fields

Filled in they look like this:

[image: screen shot]

Originally they look similar:

[image: screen shot]

This vertical compression is again caused by the field widget rectangles having a different aspect ratio than the respectively matching normal appearance stream bounding box:

- A widget rectangle: `[ 278.6 642.928 458.36 657.96 ]`, i.e. 179.76*15.032.
- The appearance bounding box: `[ 0 0 179.76 58.56 ]`, i.e. 179.76*58.56.

Just like in the case of the Resident Name fields above it is necessary to remove the old appearances before setting the new value to make PDFBox create a proper appearance.

#### A complication

Actually there is an additional issue when filling in the Care Providers Address fields, after removing the old appearances they look like this:

[image: screen shot]

This is due to a shortcoming of PDFBox: These fields are configured as multi line text fields. While PDFBox for single line text fields properly calculates the font size based on the content and later finely makes sure that the text vertically fits quite well, it proceeds very crudely for multi line fields, it selects a hard coded font size of 12 and does not fine tune the vertical position, see the code of the `AppearanceGeneratorHelper` methods `calculateFontSize(PDFont, PDRectangle)` and `insertGeneratedAppearance(PDAnnotationWidget, PDAppearanceStream, OutputStream)`.

As in your form these address fields anyways are only one line high, an obvious solution would be to make these fields single line fields, i.e. clear the *Multiline* flag.

#### Example code

Using Java one can implement the solutions explained above like this:

```java
final int FLAG_MULTILINE = 1 << 12;
final int FLAG_COMB = 1 << 24;

PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(originalStream);
PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(doc, fontStream, false);
String font_name = acroForm.getDefaultResources().add(font).getName();

for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
    if (field instanceof PDTextField) {
        PDTextField textField = (PDTextField) field;
        textField.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.MAX_LEN);
        textField.getCOSObject().setFlag(COSName.FF, FLAG_COMB | FLAG_MULTILINE, false);;
        textField.setDefaultAppearance(String.format("/%s 0 Tf 0 g", font_name));
        textField.getWidgets().forEach(w -> w.getAppearance().setNormalAppearance((PDAppearanceEntry)null));
        textField.setValue("Test");
    }
}
```

*([FillInForm](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/FillInForm.java#L398) test `testFill0DropOldAppearanceNoCombNoMaxNoMultiLine`)*

#### Screen shots of the output of the example code

The Resident Name field value now is not vertically compressed anymore:

[image: screen shot]

The Phone and Care Providers Address fields also look appropriate now:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: The flag comb `COSName.FF, FLAG_COMB` setting was particularly helpful in this solution. I could not find anywhere in the documentation or example where this was utilized - your example code could honestly be an example case that they put on the PDFBox site.

Comment: @mkl "PDFBox unfortunately re-uses the appearance stream" - I believe either you or Maruan mentioned somewhere that the PDF specification requires this to be reused.

Comment: @Xenyal although interesting, your problem seems unrealistic: usually one would get a PDF file with fields empty to write data into, or with fields filled to read data from them. Your problem is fields filled and must be changed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *"I believe either you or Maruan mentioned somewhere that the PDF specification requires this to be reused."* - you probably mean [this comment by Maruan](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4471?focusedCommentId=16775917&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16775917). [My comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4471?focusedCommentId=16776775&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16776775) interpreted the spec a bit differently.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, Xenyal: *"Your problem is fields filled and must be changed"* - even worse, the fields are *configured* as a two character comb and the OP wants to put longer values into it, i.e. use the fields for values they were not designed for.

Comment: @mkl are you aware of any cases where after `setNormalAppearance` on the widgets, a `NullPointerException` gets thrown when trying to `setValue`?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, mkl, the example PDF was filled-in by me to show what the fields looked like once filled-in. My use-case is that I need to reset the appearances of all fields prior to filling in so that once filled-in, they look consistent.

Comment: *"are you aware of any cases where after `setNormalAppearance` on the widgets, a `NullPointerException` gets thrown when trying to `setValue`?"* - no specific ones; probably that happens for broken default appearance values, e.g. referencing non-existing fonts etc.. But I'm not an expert on that topic...

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4594 for the multiline size / position problem.

Comment: It should be noted that at this point in time PDFBox doesn't support multiline text fields with auto font sizing.

Comment: @mkl It seems that once we set the widget's appearance stream to be `null`, the widget no longer has a normal appearance stream which then causes a `NullPointerException` when trying to set a value. However, when I `setValue` on the textfield before the resetting of the widgets, that works fine. Why does the order matter in this case?

Comment: @Xenyal Which pdfbox version exactly do you use? I'm using the current development snapshot. If you use a much older version,  chances are you run into bugs fixed in the current version. Here the code above definitively runs without `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @mkl Very likely to be the case; I am currently using the jar for pdfbox-2.0.5.

Comment: @Xenyal always use the latest version. If you use maven, then use the maven versions plugin. The advantage is that you lessen the risks of getting bugs, including security bugs. The only reason not to update is if you work for equifax.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun *"It should be noted that at this point in time PDFBox doesn't support multiline text fields with auto font sizing."* - Actually code comments claim to support it in the same way as Acrobat: `// Acrobat defaults to 12 for multiline text with size 0`... ;)

Comment: @mkl sorry that the comment might be misleading - Acrobat AFAIK starts the calculation with 12 and then scales accordingly. At least that's what I've got from some test files. As you know the whole apperance createion details are undocumented. Anyway - I hope to be able to start working on that soon.