# Fill textfield with pdfbox cause an offset

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox v2 to fill forms on a interactive pdf.

I use the default apparence provided on the original pdf forms, for the font and color of the text.

there is the part of the code that fill the pdf

```
keyValMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
  if (acroformKeyList.contains(key)) {
    try {
      PDField field = acroForm.getField(key);
        if (field instanceof PDTextField) {
          (PDTextField) field).setValue(value);`
            ...
```

everything work correctly expect for a few textfield, there is a gap when the value is set by pdfBox, but when i do that manually with adobe reader there is no gap.
[image]

Here is the link of the pdf that i try to fill : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GT-xqlQn1g0aref-whNDpVu4reUkiumH

Comment: I think this is this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4594  That issue also contains a link to another SO question, with a solution at the end of the answer (make these fields single line): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938135/pdfbox-inconsistent-pdtextfield-autosize-behavior-after-setvalue

Comment: Also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4568

Comment: I don't know why, when i addded "acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true)" everything worked well for me...

Comment: Yes, that setting means that the viewer should create the appearances. Adobe will do that. But other viewers, e.g. PDF.js and PDFBox will not.

Comment: Indeed, even those small fields are multiline. Thus, the issue is that PDFBox is not very sophisticated filling multiline text fields, in particular fields which are very small to begin with. The answer Tilman pointed to in its "A complication" section describes a similar effect in case of the PDF focused on there and as work-around makes the small fields single-line only. Thus, let's close this question as duplicate of that question. Furthermore, `acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true)` is not really a solution, it delegates the appearance generation to the viewer but many viewers ignore that.